# Laravel Blade foreach combine

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have two separate `div`s, one where the images are loaded and the other where the data is displayed.

```
<div class="banner-slider-image">
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">

            <!-- Slide Item -->
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="bg" style="background-image: url(include/assets/images/main-slider/1.jpg);">
                </div>
            </div>
                                 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="banner-slider-content">
    <div class="side-text">AVANT</div>
    <div class="swiper-container banner-slider">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            @if(count($listings) > 0)
                @foreach($listings as $listing)
                    <!-- Slide Item -->
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                        <div class="content-outer">
                            <div class="content-box">
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <h5>{{$listing->first_name}} {{$listing->last_name}}</h5>
                                    <h1><span>{{$listing->name}}</span> </h1>
                                    <div class="text">{{$listing->property_description}}.</div>
                                    <div class="link-box"><a href="#">View Listing</a></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            @endif

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So the first `div` will also be in a foreach loop, but I dont know how I can combine the two where they show the same related data.

Comment: If you want to combine them put them on the same div, why do they have to be seperate?

Comment: i dont see any similarity between the two div. but it they are equal you can simply just include one div and use them everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 foreach loops . It is the easiest and desired solution for you. or you can define two variable and concat the contents using one forloop and then display them later  like

```
@php
$first='';
$second='';
@endphp
 @if(count($listings) > 0)
    @foreach($listings as $listing)
       @php
       $first.='first div content';
       $second.='second div content';
       @endphp
     @endforeach
   @endif
  <div class="banner-slider-image">
        <div class="swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                 {!!$first!!}                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="banner-slider-content">
        <div class="side-text">AVANT</div>
        <div class="swiper-container banner-slider">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              {!!$second!!}
      
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Tried this, doesn't seem to work

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<body>
    @section('sidebar')
        This is the master sidebar.
    @show

    <div class="container">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
</body>
```

use for yield

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).